# Chrome no fonts

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I don't know why but chrome have no fonts and the tests are not working, see print screen :
[image]
Here you have the nightwatch log:
[log.txt](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/files/2205775/log.txt)

I'm using the last version of all the package:

"selenium-server": "^3.13.0",

"chromedriver": "^2.40.0",

"nightwatch": "^0.9.21",

"nightwatch-helpers": "^1.2.0",

chrome:
chrome version "67.0.3396.99"

I'm on Mac High Sierra: 10.13.6

Any idea what happening?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you on mac book ?

Comment: yes, i'm on a macbook, did you have the same issue?

Comment: but I have also the same behavior on Jenkins (ubuntu), with the screenschot fucntionnality I can see that I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: No I don’t own macbook :( . Have seen couple of times this  issue in macbook though .